# Get height required to scrollbar be in disabled state

Tags: python, tkinter, height, scrollbar, tk-toolkit

How to automatically resize window, so scrollbar is not scrollable, like in below picture? I've looked at every member function of scrollbar widget, there's nothing but `.state()` that returns empty tuple when scrollbar is enabled and contains `'disabled'` string otherwise. So I hacked together this, well, not so pretty function that increases height by 20px until there's `'disabled'` in `.state()`.

Here's the function:

```
class ChatUI:
    def __init__(self, master, engine):
        #  ... unrelated code ...
        self.geo_split_pattern = re.compile(r'[x+]')

    #  ... lot of unrelated code ...

    def fittofriendlist(self):
        # resizes window so all contacts are visible. horrible hack but working
        while 'disabled' not in self.friendsscroll.state():
            width = self.geo_split_pattern.split(self.master.geometry())[0]
            height = self.geo_split_pattern.split(self.master.geometry())[1]
            self.master.geometry('{0}x{1}'.format(width, int(height) + 20))
            self.master.update()

    #  ... lot more of unrelated code ...
```

What I want to achieve: (by proper way)
  [image: resize chat]

Answer (score 0):

The key isn't to ask the scrollbar what its height is, but to ask the widget it is controlling how much of its contents is visible. You can call the `yview` command which will return a tuple that describes what part of the contents is in view.

From the official tcl/tk documentation:

> ...Each element is a real fraction between 0 and 1; together they
>   describe the vertical span that is visible in the window. For example,
>   if the first element is .6 and the second element is 1.0, the lowest
>   40% of the canvas's area (as defined by the -scrollregion option) is
>   visible in the window...